# importing special characters

Tags: c#

Environment: ASP.NET 3.5
How do I import these special characters properly? What's best way to figure out encoding of character?

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(
                                           Request.Files[0].InputStream, 
                                           Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));

string csv = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSV parsing library - there are many free and open source ones for .NET, and even a [built in one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace.

The library can take care of parsing the CSV and you will be able to read the content.